# How do I use quotes on cmd in Visual Basic?

Tags: vba, cmd

I was working on a project meant for ROM hacks. I tried doing this:

`Shell("CMD.EXE / c set /p ROM=Please drag And drop your ROM here: & copy %ROM% "ROM/ROM.sfc"")`

However, I get an error, plus, I tried other tricks but what I got is an instant window close. Could someone help with me (plus, my programming skills are still developed)?

Comment: Turn internal double quotes into double double quotes. ``"`` to ``""``

Comment: That said, without the escapes, your command should look more like this: `"cmd.exe /V /D /C "Set /P "ROM=Please drag and drop your ROM here: " & Copy /Y !ROM! ROM\ROM.sfc""`. The OS should automatically doublequote a dropped path with spaces and other poison characters. But more importantly, as you're trying to do it all in one line, you need to use delayed expansion, hence the `/V` option. _The `/D` option prevents any possible autorun commands from affecting the cmd.exe instance_. Please Open a Command Prompt window, type `cmd /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, for its usage information.

Comment: You would also need to be sure, as you appear not to be using full paths, that the current working directory of the opened cmd.exe instance is predetermined to ensure that it is the intended one, _(containing an existing directory named `ROM`)_. Please also note that I used a backward slash for its directory separator, in my previous comment, as that is what Windows uses.

Comment: @PatrickK When I tried it, the cmd window just closed.